# dropbox style file selection on webpage with google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm working on a system for our customers (400+ web sites) which allow their customer to upload a file on their web page. So, to clear up that muddy description, our customer is CustomerA and customerA's customer is CustomerB.  CustomerA will have a webpage that has a javascript link in it that points back to our servers.  That javascript uses angularjs to inject some functionality into their (CustomerA) page.  Part of that functionality is allowing customerB to upload files to customerA (actually it gets posted to our REST api and we deliver the file to customerA).  Dropbox offers a quick and simple way to integrate this via their dropin javascript.  I have that up and running and it was a breeze to set up.

So now I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to allow customerB who has a google drive account to click a button on customerA's site (via the angular injected code) that loads a popup window with their drive contents so they can select a file to upload/share.  The way that dropbox does it is that when a user selects a file, I'm given a url to the file that expires after 4 hours.  Is there something like this with the google drive sdk?  Everything that I'm seeing/reading sounds like it's geared toward writing an app that integrates within google drive rather than google drive integrating with a web page.  I also watched the quickstart video and learned how to set up an oauth app, but it looks like I have to register every domain for our customers that could be using our system - ugghh.  Is that right?  Thanks.

Comment: to clarify, the popup should show files from Customer B's Drive account, or B's hard drive?? That file will then be passed/uploaded to your REST API (which then uploads it to A's Drive account).  It's all doable. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Customer B's drive account.  The issue is I'm not clear on how to actually do this.  The quick start video shows where to go to find settings, but the screens have changed and no longer match.  Their code on this page https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing has two variables in it FILE_ID and YOUR_APP_ID.  What is FILE_ID?  If I log into my account I see a Project Id but no App Id, so are these the same?  When I try to use it, nothing on the page works. Maybe that's related to the FILE_ID?  Half baked example code and Inconsistencies make it hard to know how to do things.

Comment: A lot of questions in there. On the domain registration question, for security reasons the Javascript must be running from a registered origin. Provided you can pop up (or poss iframe, but I've never tried) the "picker" from a registered domain, you will be OK. The other alternative is to look at the Google Drive Picker library https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/.

Comment: If you want to DIY in angular, it might be worth looking at https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngGAPI/blob/dev/nggapi-lib/minimal.html . This is a library I'm currently working on to take all the pain away from Angular/Drive/OAuth. It's currently at Alpha stage, but is maturing rapidly.

Comment: Great, I think the picker is exactly what I'm looking for but I'll also take a look at the github project.  Regarding the domain issue, if that's the way it has to be, so be it.  I just hoping there'd be an alternative.  Thanks so much!  Feel free to make yours an answer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: Good luck. I would suggest leaving the question un-answered until you've got a working solution, then post your own answer. That will make the Q&A more valuable for those who follow.